# Primary sources grouped by text name

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm having trouble with the formatting of primary sources in my bibliography. I work on several texts, most of which are anonymous and edited several times. I'd like the "primary sources" section of my bibliography to contain entries of the form:

> [Text title]
>
> - Reference to edition 1
> - Reference to edition 2

I know that this can be done (see, e.g., [this article](http://www.alexissanderson.com/uploads/6/2/7/6/6276908/saiva_exegesis_with_front_matter.pdf), from p. 217 of the PDF = p. 551 of the book proper). But I don't know how.

Comment: What do you use to compose your bibliography?

Comment: ilFuria: I use Biber to compile the bibliography. As concerns data entry, I do everything by hand.

Comment: Welcome! So, not `bibtex`, then, despite the tag.

Comment: Have you considered asking the author for the configuration? Otherwise, please provide an MWEB (Minimum Working Example with Bibliography) for people to work with.

Comment: It seems a case where you can use the entry type `set` and `entryset` facilities of biblatex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use filtering by keyword.

Add keywords "work1", "work2" etc to your entry, and then do

`\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}}
\printbibliography[keyword=work1,title=Title1]
\printbibliography[keyword=work2,title=Title2]
\printbibliography[keyword=work3,title=Title3]
etc.`

Here, bibliography or on `section` level.